# Rotate 2D object linearly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

My 2D object is looking up (`transform.up = (0,1)`).

When I click somewhere in the screen, I want the object to look to where I clicked. I also want it to rotate linearly: it should rotate `d` degrees per second, implying that it takes twice the time to rotate twice the angle.

Here is my code:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Vector2 wPos = cameraRef.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        StartCoroutine(LookAt(mouseScreenPosition));
    }   
}

public IEnumerator LookAt(Vector2 position) {
    Vector2 direction = (position - (Vector2) transform.position).normalized;
    float angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(direction, transform.up);
    float startAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;

    for(float t = 0; t <= 1; t += Time.deltaTime * (180 / Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Abs(angle)))) {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, startAngle - angle, t));
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The factor I multiply `Time.deltaTime` is `180 / Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Abs(angle))`, which says that the bigger the angle, the bigger the time it takes to rotate, but I don't know if I'm doing it right (it works) or if this is the better way to do it.

Comment: did you find a solution to this that worked for you?

Comment: I'm studying a little about Quaternion so I can understand your solution better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some `rotationSpeed` field:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 90f;
```

Use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to get the `Quaternion` you want to rotate towards. You want the local forward to point in the global forward direction and local up to point towards the target position, so use `Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward,targetDirection)`:

```
public IEnumerator LookAt(Vector2 position) {
    // casting to Vector2 and normalizing is redundant
    Vector3 targetDirection = position - transform.position; 
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, targetDirection);
```

Then use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) with the max amount of degrees you want to rotate in that frame until you are done rotating toward the goal rotation:

```
while (Quaternion.Angle(targetRotation, transform.rotation) > 0.01) 
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation,
            time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
}
```

Altogether:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 90f;

public IEnumerator LookAt(Vector2 position) {
    // casting to Vector2 and normalizing is redundant
    Vector3 targetDirection = position - transform.position; 
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, targetDirection);

    while (Quaternion.Angle(targetRotation, transform.rotation) > 0.01) 
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation,
                time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way? I mean, every iteration you need to call `Quaternion.Angle` to verify the angle, but I guess once you have the value, you wouldn't need to verify every frame.

Comment: You could keep track of how many degrees you've turned but this ensures that if any other script changes the rotation while the coroutine is operating, you are guaranteed to keep turning until it faces the goal.